# What is wrong with this MySQL 'insert' statement?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm having one of those moments, there must be a simple error in my MySQL but I just can't find it! I have tried an online syntax checker but it hasn't helped, I can't seem to identify the error.

The error I get is:

> `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'property_ground_rent, property_ground_rent_unit,
>   property_ground_rent_vat, prope'

```
$property_sql="INSERT INTO property (
property_token,
property_availability,
property_auction,
property_status,
property_category,
property_type,
property_apartment_number_name,
property_number_name,
property_address_line_1,
property_address_line_2,
property_suburb,
property_town_city,
property_postcode,
property_country,
property_display_address,
property_epc_rating,
property_local_authority,
property_council_tax_band,
property_rateable_value,
property_no_bedrooms,
property_no_bathrooms,
property_no_receptions,
property_no_outbuildings,
property_no_floors,
property_entrance_floor,
property_new_build,
property_condition,
property_tenure_type,
property_leasehold_date,
property_leasehold_term,
property_year_built,
property_living_space,
property_living_space_unit,
property_land_size,
property_land_size_unit,
property_summary,
property_description,
property_commercial_price_per_unit_area,
property_service_charge,
property_service_charge_unit,
property_service_charge_vat,
property_insurance,
property_insurance_unit,
property_insurance_vat
property_ground_rent,
property_ground_rent_unit,
property_ground_rent_vat,
property_commercial_business_for_sale,
property_price,
property_price_vat,
property_price_qualifier,
property_letting_rent_frequency,
property_letting_deposit,
property_contract_type,
property_letting_student,
property_letting_share,
property_letting_minimum_term,
property_letting_contract_term,
property_letting_term_type,
property_letting_available_from,
property_letting_furnished_status,
property_letting_lha,
property_letting_pets,
property_letting_smoking,
property_letting_sharers,
property_letting_burglar_alarm,
property_letting_tenant_fees,
property_date_created,
property_date_updated,
property_created_by,
property_updated_by,
property_parking_spaces,
property_letting_type,
property_letting_service,
property_letting_tenancy_renewal_fee,
property_account_manager,
property_branch,
property_tenant_find_fee,
property_management_fee,
property_tenant_find_fee_type,
property_management_fee_type,
property_sole_sale_fee,
property_multi_sale_fee,
property_sole_sale_fee_type,
property_multi_sale_fee_type,
property_letting_all_bills_included,
property_letting_water_bill,
property_letting_gas_bill,
property_letting_electricity_bill,
property_letting_oil_bill,
property_letting_council_tax,
property_letting_tv_licence,
property_letting_sat_cable_tv_bill,
property_letting_internet_bill,
property_letting_telephone_bill,
property_letting_service_charge,
property_letting_ground_rent,
property_mains_gas_supply,
property_viewing_arrangement,
property_viewing_arrangement_notes,
property_keys_location,
property_lll_status,
property_latitude,
property_longitude,
property_notes
)
VALUES (
'" . generateRandomString(40) . "',
'$property_availability',
'$property_auction',
'$property_status',
'$property_category',
'$property_type',
'$property_apartment_number_name',
'$property_number_name',
'$property_address_line_1',
'$property_address_line_2',
'$property_suburb',
'$property_town_city',
'$property_postcode',
'$property_country',
'$property_display_address',
'$property_epc_rating',
'$property_local_authority',
'$property_council_tax_band',
'$property_rateable_value',
'$property_no_bedrooms',
'$property_no_bathrooms',
'$property_no_receptions',
'$property_no_outbuildings',
'$property_no_floors',
'$property_entrance_floor',
'$property_new_build',
'$property_condition',
'$property_tenure_type',
'$property_leasehold_date',
'$property_leasehold_term',
'$property_year_built',
'$property_living_space',
'$property_living_space_unit',
'$property_land_size',
'$property_land_size_unit',
'$property_summary',
'$property_description',
'$property_commercial_price_per_unit_area',
'$property_service_charge',
'$property_service_charge_unit',
'$property_service_charge_vat',
'$property_insurance',
'$property_insurance_unit',
'$property_insurance_vat',
'$property_ground_rent',
'$property_ground_rent_unit',
'$property_ground_rent_vat',
'$property_commercial_business_for_sale',
'$property_price',
'$property_price_vat',
'$property_price_qualifier',
'$property_letting_rent_frequency',
'$property_letting_deposit',
'$property_contract_type',
'$property_letting_student',
'$property_letting_share',
'$property_letting_minimum_term',
'$property_letting_contract_term',
'$property_letting_term_type',
'$property_letting_available_from',
'$property_letting_furnished_status',
'$property_letting_lha',
'$property_letting_pets',
'$property_letting_smoking',
'$property_letting_sharers',
'$property_letting_burglar_alarm',
'$property_letting_tenant_fees',
'$property_date_created',
'$property_date_updated',
'$property_created_by',
'$property_updated_by',
'$property_parking_spaces',
'$property_letting_type',
'$property_letting_service',
'$property_letting_tenancy_renewal_fee',
'$property_account_manager',
'$property_branch',
'$property_tenant_find_fee',
'$property_management_fee',
'$property_tenant_find_fee_type',
'$property_management_fee_type',
'$property_sole_sale_fee',
'$property_multi_sale_fee',
'$property_sole_sale_fee_type',
'$property_multi_sale_fee_type',
'$property_letting_all_bills_included',
'$property_letting_water_bill',
'$property_letting_gas_bill',
'$property_letting_electricity_bill',
'$property_letting_oil_bill',
'$property_letting_council_tax',
'$property_letting_tv_licence',
'$property_letting_sat_cable_tv_bill',
'$property_letting_internet_bill',
'$property_letting_telephone_bill',
'$property_letting_service_charge',
'$property_letting_ground_rent',
'$property_mains_gas_supply',
'$property_viewing_arrangement',
'$property_viewing_arrangement_notes',
'$property_keys_location',
'$property_lll_status',
'$property_latitude',
'$property_longitude',
'$property_notes'
)";
```

Comment: You missed comma `,` before `property_ground_rent`

Comment: Now you have the answer you should delete the question.  Typo questions are of no benefit to future site uses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a comma `,` after `property_insurance_vat`

```
$property_sql="INSERT INTO property (
property_token,
property_availability,
property_auction,
property_status,
property_category,
property_type,
property_apartment_number_name,
property_number_name,
property_address_line_1,
property_address_line_2,
property_suburb,
property_town_city,
property_postcode,
property_country,
property_display_address,
property_epc_rating,
property_local_authority,
property_council_tax_band,
property_rateable_value,
property_no_bedrooms,
property_no_bathrooms,
property_no_receptions,
property_no_outbuildings,
property_no_floors,
property_entrance_floor,
property_new_build,
property_condition,
property_tenure_type,
property_leasehold_date,
property_leasehold_term,
property_year_built,
property_living_space,
property_living_space_unit,
property_land_size,
property_land_size_unit,
property_summary,
property_description,
property_commercial_price_per_unit_area,
property_service_charge,
property_service_charge_unit,
property_service_charge_vat,
property_insurance,
property_insurance_unit,
property_insurance_vat, //------------>You missed comma
property_ground_rent,
property_ground_rent_unit,
property_ground_rent_vat,
property_commercial_business_for_sale,
property_price,
property_price_vat,
property_price_qualifier,
property_letting_rent_frequency,
property_letting_deposit,
property_contract_type,
property_letting_student,
property_letting_share,
property_letting_minimum_term,
property_letting_contract_term,
property_letting_term_type,
property_letting_available_from,
property_letting_furnished_status,
property_letting_lha,
property_letting_pets,
property_letting_smoking,
property_letting_sharers,
property_letting_burglar_alarm,
property_letting_tenant_fees,
property_date_created,
property_date_updated,
property_created_by,
property_updated_by,
property_parking_spaces,
property_letting_type,
property_letting_service,
property_letting_tenancy_renewal_fee,
property_account_manager,
property_branch,
property_tenant_find_fee,
property_management_fee,
property_tenant_find_fee_type,
property_management_fee_type,
property_sole_sale_fee,
property_multi_sale_fee,
property_sole_sale_fee_type,
property_multi_sale_fee_type,
property_letting_all_bills_included,
property_letting_water_bill,
property_letting_gas_bill,
property_letting_electricity_bill,
property_letting_oil_bill,
property_letting_council_tax,
property_letting_tv_licence,
property_letting_sat_cable_tv_bill,
property_letting_internet_bill,
property_letting_telephone_bill,
property_letting_service_charge,
property_letting_ground_rent,
property_mains_gas_supply,
property_viewing_arrangement,
property_viewing_arrangement_notes,
property_keys_location,
property_lll_status,
property_latitude,
property_longitude,
property_notes
)
VALUES (
'" . generateRandomString(40) . "',
'$property_availability',
'$property_auction',
'$property_status',
'$property_category',
'$property_type',
'$property_apartment_number_name',
'$property_number_name',
'$property_address_line_1',
'$property_address_line_2',
'$property_suburb',
'$property_town_city',
'$property_postcode',
'$property_country',
'$property_display_address',
'$property_epc_rating',
'$property_local_authority',
'$property_council_tax_band',
'$property_rateable_value',
'$property_no_bedrooms',
'$property_no_bathrooms',
'$property_no_receptions',
'$property_no_outbuildings',
'$property_no_floors',
'$property_entrance_floor',
'$property_new_build',
'$property_condition',
'$property_tenure_type',
'$property_leasehold_date',
'$property_leasehold_term',
'$property_year_built',
'$property_living_space',
'$property_living_space_unit',
'$property_land_size',
'$property_land_size_unit',
'$property_summary',
'$property_description',
'$property_commercial_price_per_unit_area',
'$property_service_charge',
'$property_service_charge_unit',
'$property_service_charge_vat',
'$property_insurance',
'$property_insurance_unit',
'$property_insurance_vat',
'$property_ground_rent',
'$property_ground_rent_unit',
'$property_ground_rent_vat',
'$property_commercial_business_for_sale',
'$property_price',
'$property_price_vat',
'$property_price_qualifier',
'$property_letting_rent_frequency',
'$property_letting_deposit',
'$property_contract_type',
'$property_letting_student',
'$property_letting_share',
'$property_letting_minimum_term',
'$property_letting_contract_term',
'$property_letting_term_type',
'$property_letting_available_from',
'$property_letting_furnished_status',
'$property_letting_lha',
'$property_letting_pets',
'$property_letting_smoking',
'$property_letting_sharers',
'$property_letting_burglar_alarm',
'$property_letting_tenant_fees',
'$property_date_created',
'$property_date_updated',
'$property_created_by',
'$property_updated_by',
'$property_parking_spaces',
'$property_letting_type',
'$property_letting_service',
'$property_letting_tenancy_renewal_fee',
'$property_account_manager',
'$property_branch',
'$property_tenant_find_fee',
'$property_management_fee',
'$property_tenant_find_fee_type',
'$property_management_fee_type',
'$property_sole_sale_fee',
'$property_multi_sale_fee',
'$property_sole_sale_fee_type',
'$property_multi_sale_fee_type',
'$property_letting_all_bills_included',
'$property_letting_water_bill',
'$property_letting_gas_bill',
'$property_letting_electricity_bill',
'$property_letting_oil_bill',
'$property_letting_council_tax',
'$property_letting_tv_licence',
'$property_letting_sat_cable_tv_bill',
'$property_letting_internet_bill',
'$property_letting_telephone_bill',
'$property_letting_service_charge',
'$property_letting_ground_rent',
'$property_mains_gas_supply',
'$property_viewing_arrangement',
'$property_viewing_arrangement_notes',
'$property_keys_location',
'$property_lll_status',
'$property_latitude',
'$property_longitude',
'$property_notes'
)";
```